# how to save values of textview in fragments in android

Tags: android, savestate

I am working on eCommerce app how can i save values of quantity which is in a listview of each products user selected so that he can edit it later as well if he comes from cart screen. Should I use saveInstanceState for this or is there any other optimised way?

i am not giving any wishlist kind of thing as we have in flipkart but i want to save the quantities selected by user for each product so that if he wants to change it he can change it later on. productlisting screen(where products can be selected)-->cart screen--> productlisting screen(it should display the quantities selected by the user in front of each product)

Comment: imho an ecommerce needs to have an user account in which save what the user wants. That's means that you will need a server side with a database, a registration/login screen and if you want save something save it in the db so the user can see his products when he wants. By the way, you could save the textview string (String s = textview.getText().toString() to get the string of textview) in the sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are working with eCommerce app that has the facility to save product (**like Add to cart in Amazon or Flipkart** ) best way to save in Android's SharedPreferences. It is file based(saved in XML) so donn't load in memory for long time.

Comment: i am not giving any wishlist kind of thing as we have in flipkart but i want to save the quantities selected by user for each product so that if he wants to change it he can change it later on.                                                                      productlisting screen(where products can be selected)-->cart screen--> productlisting screen(it should display the quantities selected by the user in front of each product)

Comment: yes, Sharedpreferences will be a proper solution for your requirement. Its quite easy to use,too. take a look http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html